# Query string url to seo friendly url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

i am trying to rewrite a URL for SEO purpose.

The old URL is:

```
http://www.example.com/recipe_local.php?hl_cusine=1
```

The new URL should be like bellow and automatic redirect to this url if user come above url

```
http://www.example.com/recipes/healthy-recipes
```

My Code in the .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^recipes/healthy-recipes/$ recipe_local.php?hl_cusine=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^recipes/healthy-recipes$ recipe_local.php?hl_cusine=$1 [NC,L]
```

Even after hours of research, i have no clue why this is not working :(

Comment: What URL are you going to and what are you expecting to see?

Comment: How can `healthy-recipes` become `hl_cusine=1` in rewrite rules only?

Comment: You are trying to do things at once (as people frequently do in this scenario). First, you want to make it so that when a user types in `http://www.example.com/recipes/healthy-recipes/42`, it acts as though they typed `http://www.example.com/recipe_local.php?hl_cusine=42` (internal rewrite). Second, with a completely different rule, you want to make it so that when a user actually types `http://www.example.com/recipe_local.php?hl_cusine=42`, their browser is told to instead load `http://www.example.com/recipes/healthy-recipes/42` (external redirect).

Answer (score 1):

The `$1` in your rewrite is pointing to a backreference you never capture.
Unless you have a `RewriteCond` you are not showing?
try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^recipes/healthy-recipes/$ recipe_local.php?hl_cusine=1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^recipes/healthy-recipes$ recipe_local.php?hl_cusine=1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: @Michael...now url is opens like http://www.example.com/recipes/healthy-recipes but its not redirect automatically

Comment: can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I am trying to add in pagination...so it will take parameter from url and make dynamic url 
http://www.example.com/recipe_local.php?page=2&hl_cusine=1
to
http://www.example.com/recipes/healthy-recipes/1/